# Im not able to install any plugin on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ide, eclipse-oxygen

I have an Eclipse Oxygen installed on my MAC.

I have installed few plugins before, but recently I am not able to install any plugins.

I keep getting some weird error message. If you can let me know what I can do to fix it I will really appreciate it.

Screenshot attached of the

[image: popup error message]

Comment: What screen shot?

Comment: Please provide additional information in your question buddy. It is impossible to help you with what you have currently written.

Comment: I just added the screen shot , can you see it?